# Laravel PHP - Convert a string to array from DB

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, parsing

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$variable = Model::where($data)->get();
```

$data is stored in the database as `['type' => 1, 'status' => 2]`

I cannot seem to be able to parse the data from a string to array properly, the best I have gotten close to is

```
0 => "['type' => 1, 'status' => 2]"
```

How can I properly parse this array from DB -> variable in php?

Comment: That’s not a deserializable format. You _should_ write a custom parser for it, but that particular string can be evaluated: `$array = eval("return $data;");`

Comment: It would be better if you changed the way the data is stored and used something like JSON instead.

Comment: @rickdenhaan - oh yeah noted thank you.

Comment: @NigelRen - I agree, thank you, JSON would be easier to manage actually

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it using the following:

```
$data = "['type' => 1, 'status' => 2]";
$variable = Model::where(eval("return $data;"))->get();
```

This will work properly.

Cleaned and Updated as @rickdenhaan recommended.

Comment: Just a quick note: if you're defining `$data` yourself like here in this code sample, it's best to avoid `eval()` and just write `$data = ['type' => 1, 'status' => 2];` (without the `"` marks), then `$data` will already be an array. This is basically what `eval()` is doing with your string anyway.